# upgrade 14.04 - 14.10 - 15.04 - 15.10

Tags: 14.04, 15.10

Can I upgrade to an unsupported version of ubuntu? I want to know it because I want to move from 14.04 - 14.10 - 15.04 and finally to 15.10.

Comment: No. And why  not wait for 16.04 and do a 14.04 LTS->16.04 LTS?

Comment: You potentially could, but it takes far more time consuming, work, and bandwidth and is much more error prone then simply doing a fresh install of 15.10 or ever 16.04. With a fresh install your data in /home will be preserved as long as you do not format the partition /home is on (/ by default)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you **can** - but I sincerely can't recommend you to do that.

First of all, it would take a **great** amount of time to upgrade through all of those version. I could risk to say about 1 hour each.

Also many people suffer from bugs (mainly with configuration files and strange behaviors) when they upgrade from the Software Updater. This amount of upgrades could (and probably will) lead you to a few annoying bugs.

So I'll recommend you to do a **fresh install**. Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download , grab the ISO from the version you want and replace your old Ubuntu version with the new one. **Remember to backup all of your important files**.

Doing a fresh install will take you a lot less time and you'll avoid headaches.

Finally, Wily Werewolf (15.10) is a regular release and will reach its end of life in July this year. So you might consider waiting for Xenial Xerus' (16.04) release, in April, to upgrade, since it's a Long Term Support version.